# Phonegap cordova_plugins.js Throwing Error 500

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

In my Phonegap project, the following error is shown in the browser's console:

```
GET http://192.168.137.1:3000/cordova_plugins.js 500 (Internal Server Error)
  exports.injectScript @ cordova.js:1528
  injectIfNecessary @ cordova.js:1536
  exports.load @ cordova.js:1616
  (anonymous) @ cordova.js:1129
```

When I go to `http://192.168.137.1:3000/cordova_plugins.js`, it shows:

```
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
   at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
   at Object.join (path.js:466:7)
   at Object.handle (C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\PhoneGap\PhoneGap Desktop\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\connect-phonegap\lib\middleware\cordova\cordova_plugins.js:18:33)
   at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\PhoneGap\PhoneGap Desktop\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:174:15)
   at Object.handle (C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\PhoneGap\PhoneGap Desktop\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\connect-phonegap\lib\middleware\cordova\cordova.js:33:13)
   at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\PhoneGap\PhoneGap Desktop\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:174:15)
   at SendStream.error (C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\PhoneGap\PhoneGap Desktop\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:120:7)
   at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
   at SendStream.emit (events.js:188:7)
   at SendStream.error (C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\PhoneGap\PhoneGap Desktop\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\send\index.js:245:17)
```

The general cause for `cordova_plugins.js` errors seems to be including it in the app's html, but I am not doing this; the only cordova script I'm including is `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>`.

Does anyone know what's going on and how to solve the error?

Comment: what version of your cordova

Comment: I don't specify, so it gets the latest I think